# React Convert RGB Decimal Color to Background color

Tags: css, reactjs, rgb

I am receiving rgb colors in decimal value.

Example: "The Decimal color 16776960 is a light color, and the websafe version is hex FFFF00, and the color name is yellow. The color can be described as light saturated yellow."

I need to take these decimal color values (from API) and show their background color in React. The following is not working. How can this be done?

```
<TableCell>
    <Box style={{ background: `rgb(${row.rgbColor})` }}>
        {row.rgbColor}
    </Box>
</TableCell>
```

Using Resource: [React set background color with state rgb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50571471/react-set-background-color-with-state-rgb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use decimal to hex javascript code.

```
<TableCell>
    <Box style={{ background: parseInt(row.rgbColor, 16) }}>
        {row.rgbColor}
    </Box>
</TableCell>
```

I hope it will work for you.

Comment: hi, I had to convert like into this which works, 'rgbColorView: `${Math.floor(x.rgbColor / (256 * 256))},
        ${Math.floor(x.rgbColor / 256) % 256}, ${x.rgbColor % 256}`,  feel free to edit and test answer, and I can send you points, above answer did not work, thanks